# Python sum dict values based on keys

Tags: python, json, parsing, dictionary

How to sum values from dict where values are string. I mean how to sum values where multiply key is same in dictionary.

## dict

```
values = [
    {
        "rashod": 0,
        "prihod": 230.0,
        "prod_name": "r",
        "prod_hola": "t"
    },
    {
        "rashod": 0,
        "prihod": 230.0,
        "prod_name": "r",
        "prod_hola": "t"
    },
    {
        "rashod": 0.0,
        "prihod": 0,
        "prod_name": "c",
        "prod_hola": "f"
    },
    {
        "rashod": 0,
        "prihod": 100.0,
        "prod_name": "c",
        "prod_hola": "f"
    },
    {
        "rashod": 0.0,
        "prihod": 0,
        "prod_name": "a",
        "prod_hola": "b"
    },
    {
        "rashod": 0,
        "prihod": 1500.0,
        "prod_name": "a",
        "prod_hola": "b"
    }]
```

## python

```
dictf = reduce(lambda x, y: dict((k, v + y[k]) for k, v in x.iteritems()), values)
print dictf
```

But this sum all values in dict, and output is like:

```
{'rashod': 1930.0, 'prihod': -17020.0, 'prod_name': 'abcfrtabcfrtabcfrt'}
```

What I want is output like this:

```
[{'rashod': 1930.0, 'prihod': -17020.0, 'prod_name': 'a','prod_hola':'b},
{'rashod': 1930.0, 'prihod': -17020.0, 'prod_name': 'c','prod_hola':'f},
{'rashod': 1930.0, 'prihod': -17020.0, 'prod_name': 'r','prod_hola':'t},]
```

Comment: provide output that matches the input.

Comment: Your input/output example are ambigous : should values be regrouped on "prod_name" only, "prod_hola" only or the combination of "prod_name" and "prod_hola" ?

Comment: they are combination of "prod_name" and "prod_hola"

Comment: Oh and yes: a Karoly Horvarth mentions, your example output doesn't match the input - could you provide matching input and output samples please ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Specific solution, with no attempt at cleverness:

```
def regroup(values):
    groups = dict()
    for d in values:
        key = (d["prod_name"], d["prod_hola"])
        if key in groups:
            group = groups[key]
            group["rashod"] += d["rashod"]
            group["prihod"] += d["prihod"]
        else:
            groups[key] = d.copy()
    return list(groups.values())
```

And a slightly more generic solution:

```
def generic_regroup(values, keys):
    groups = dict()
    valkeys = [k for k in values[0] if k not in key]
    for d in values:
        key = tuple(d[k] for k in keys)
        if key in groups:
            group = groups[key]
            for k in valkeys:
                group[k] += d[k]
        else:
            groups[key] = d.copy()
    return list(groups.values())

results = generic_regroup(values, ("prod_name", "prod_hola"))
```

Now someone will certainly chime in with a much more clever solution involving itertools...

Comment: Any suggestion for this : 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66974191/get-sum-of-elemets-in-json-store-data-kivy-to-resolve-scroll-height-question

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple and specific solution, I am sure there are more general and cleverer ones.
:)

```
from collections import defaultdict

pr = defaultdict(float)
ra = defaultdict(float)
for el in values:
    combi = (el['prod_name'], el['prod_hola'])
    pr[combi] += el['prihod']
    ra[combi] += el['rashod']

results = [dict(rashod=r, prihod=p, \
                prod_name=nh[0], prod_hola=nh[1]) \
           for r,p,nh in zip(ra.values(), pr.values(), pr)]
print results
```

gives

```
[{'rashod': 0.0, 'prihod': 100.0, 'prod_name': 'c', 'prod_hola': 'f'},
 {'rashod': 0.0, 'prihod': 1500.0, 'prod_name': 'a', 'prod_hola': 'b'},
 {'rashod': 0.0, 'prihod': 460.0, 'prod_name': 'r', 'prod_hola': 't'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that uses a temporary `dict` with keys based on the input `dict`'s key value pairs where the values are of type `str`:

```
def get_key(d):
    return {k: v for k, v in d.items() if isinstance(v, str)}

def sum_dicts(x, y):
    summed = {k: x.get(k, 0) + y[k] for k, v in y.items() if not isinstance(v, str)}
    summed.update(get_key(y))
    return summed

result = {}
for value in values:
    key = json.dumps(get_key(value))
    result[key] = sum_dicts(result.get(key, {}), value)

print result.values()
```

Or if you want to use `reduce()`:

```
def dict_sum_reducer(items, new):
    new_items = map(lambda x: sum_dicts(x, new) if get_key(x) == get_key(new) else x, items)
    if new_items == items:
        new_items.append(new)
    return new_items

print reduce(dict_sum_reducer, values, [])
```

Comment: Thank you for answers. It was really helpfull and learn me things.