# Python - List nested in dict - how to sum single value

Tags: python, list, dictionary, sum

I tried reading through many similar questions (this seemed closest: [Python sum dict values based on keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32632516/python-sum-dict-values-based-on-keys)) but still struggling to answer the following question below. Boiling it down to basics

I have the following 3 dictionaries with lists as keys:

```
{'milk': ['gallons', 5, 10, 50]}
{'eggs': ['cartons', 5, 2, 10]}
{'bacon': ['packages', 5, 7, 35]}
```

I want to be able to sum the last value of each nested list and have an **expected, single value** of `95` printed to the screen.

I've seen answers to similar questions that involve lambdas but I know there has to be a way to do this with iterating through the list. I've seen the use of *sum* and *Counter* and am open to any explanations.
Thank you in advance.

**UPDATE/ADDED CONTEXT**

Thank you to those who have already been responding. I realize more context may be needed to answer this.

These entries are being made from this class:

```
class GroceryCart(dict):

    def __init__(self):
        self = {}

    def addToCart(self, item, units, quantity, price):
        item_total = quantity*price
        self.update({item:[units, quantity, price, item_total]})

    def returnCart(self):
        return self

my_cart = GroceryCart()
```

That is where you are getting the funky structure of info.
I tried @ggorlan's response below but got traceback errors about not having str values to use `.values()`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "grocery_store.py", line 156, in <module>
    total = sum(sum(y[-1] for y in x.values()) for x in my_cart)
  File "grocery_store.py", line 156, in <genexpr>
    total = sum(sum(y[-1] for y in x.values()) for x in my_cart)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'values'
```

Comment: Lists can't be keys in a dictionary. Lists can only be values (as you have in your example). Also, are these three dictionaries in a larger data structure?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: if your dictionary is a then sum([a[k][3] for k in a])  will print 95, but you have to write a as {'bacon': ['packages', 5, 7, 35],
 'eggs': ['cartons', 5, 2, 10],
 'milk': ['gallons', 5, 10, 50]}

Comment: I've tried adapting things like [this list comprehension and loop example](http://blog.rizauddin.com/2009/05/how-to-sum-values-of-python-dictionary_7174.html) and from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11692613/python-sum-values-in-dictionary) trying to experiment with the solution to see if it can be applied to my scenario. Tbh it's been a lot of flailing and trying to systematically drill down to find out how to call the last value of the list. But if I can do that, would I store it in a new list to sum after iterating through?

Comment: I think you need to step back and tell us what you're trying to do in a broader way. This looks like a wrong way to manage your data.

Comment: @NoufalIbrahim Just added more context. You are right--this has a lot to do with me being new to python. Hence the weird data management.

Comment: Are you sure you want to subclass from `dict`? I'd create an internal variable that's a dict which stores the data. Something like `self.items = {}` rather than subclass from `dict`.

Comment: Also, assigning to `self` doesn't make sense here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
foods = {
    'milk': ['gallons', 5, 10, 50],
    'eggs': ['cartons', 5, 2, 10],
    'bacon': ['packages', 5, 7, 35]
}

s = sum([item[-1] for item in foods.values()])
```

The `s` will be 95.

Answer (score 2):

This is a strange structure. It looks like your values are lists, not the keys. If I assume the three objects are in an array, here's an attempt:

```
food = [
    {'milk': ['gallons', 5, 10, 50]},
    {'eggs': ['cartons', 5, 2, 10]},
    {'bacon': ['packages', 5, 7, 35]}
]

total = sum(list(x.values())[0][-1] for x in food)
print(total) # 95
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want your dictionaries in a list, use the following code. Two `for` loops are required: the first iterates through `foods` which is a list of dictionaries and the second iterates through the values in the dictionary that's currently being iterated over. `food.values()` yields the lists in your dictionary and `lst[-1]` selects the last element from the list that's currently being iterated over.

```
foods = [
    {'milk': ['gallons', 5, 10, 50]},
    {'eggs': ['cartons', 5, 2, 10]},
    {'bacon': ['packages', 5, 7, 35]}
]

sum = 0
for food in foods:
    for details in food.values():
        sum += details[-1]
print(sum)  # 95
```

Otherwise assuming you want them as one dictionary, use the following code. This time only one `for` loop is needed to iterate through the dictionary's every value.

```
foods = {
    'milk': ['gallons', 5, 10, 50],
    'eggs': ['cartons', 5, 2, 10],
    'bacon': ['packages', 5, 7, 35]
}

sum = 0
for lst in foods.values():
    sum += lst[-1]
print(sum)  # 95
```

Comment: The second options gets me verrrrry close to what I'm after. Though the output is: 50 60 95 ||| So I'm assuming there is a small modification to only show the final sum?

Answer (score 0):

I assume, given the nature of your question that it's probably for a class assignment, in which case I would seriously consider asking your teacher/professor if they want single-key dictionaries, because it seems a lot more likely that they would want that rather than the data structure you have devised. That being said, @contrum has a lovely solution for solving it as a multi-key dictionary; Otherwise, since you've stated that you want to iterate the dictionaries and it's pretty easy to append lists, the following should work just fine for you while also having a puntastic name:

```
def getSum(dictList):
    result = 0
    dictList = [{'milk': ['gallons', 5, 10, 50]}, {'eggs': ['cartons', 5, 2, 10]}, {'bacon': ['packages', 5, 7, 35]}]
    for richard in dictList:
        for key in richard:
            result += richard[key][len(richard[key]) - 1]
    return result
```